# How to Make CSS Image Slider Move Through Slides Automatically

Tags: jquery, css

I have a CSS and HTML image slider, but I want it to move through the pictures after 3-5 seconds. I am quite happy to use JQuery but I don't know how to do this... please help? I just don't understand how to use JQuery. All help is appreciated... thankyou.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);

.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    transform: scale(0);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
}

.nav label {
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

   opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: opacity .2s;

    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 270px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
 width: 600px;
 bottom: 9px;
 height: 11px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
 top: -5px;
 width: 11px;
 height: 11px;
 margin: 0 4px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#everything {
 position:absolute;
 left:380px;
 top:330px;
}

.slide label {
 position:absolute;
 left: 50px;
 top: 20px;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border-color:white;
 width: 150px;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:Impact;
 font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "everything">
<ul class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide">
        <label>TMNT</label>
   <img src="slider/tmnt.jpg" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
        <label>Box Trolls</label>
          <img src="slider/boxtrolls.jpg" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
        <label>If I Stay</label>
          <img src="slider/ifistay.png" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
        <label>Ouija</label>
          <img src="slider/ouija.jpg" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
        <label>The Maze Runner</label>
          <img src="slider/themazerunner.png" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
        <label>Unknown</label>
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-dots">
      <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
      <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
      <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
      <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
      <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
      <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did all the comments go @Ohgodwhy ?????

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript that changes the radio button input is selected. It will cycle every 3 seconds change 3000 if you want to change the wait time. Also added in is if the user clicks on a navigation dot then the cycle will stop.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrollPosition = 2;
  var clicked = false;

  setInterval(function(){ 
    if(!clicked) {
      $('#img-' + scrollPosition).prop('checked', true);
      if(scrollPosition < 4) {
        scrollPosition += 1;
      } else {
          scrollPosition = 1;
      }
    }
  }, 3000);

  $('.nav-dot').click(function() {
    clicked = true;
  });
});
```